# Crop extended marker in colorbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, contourf

I had to use `extend='min'` in using `contourf` to include coloring the values below my given range (negative values). I'd like to ask if how do I crop this extended marker (pointed by the arrow)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap='Spectral', vmin=0, vmax=60, norm=norm, extend='min')

# colorbar
cax = fig.add_axes([.918, 0.175, 0.045, 0.6])
cb = fig.colorbar(ax, cax=cax)
```

[image]

and make it to something like this

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
bounds = [5*i for i in range(13)]
cax = fig.add_axes([.918, 0.175, 0.045, 0.6])
fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = 'Spectral', norm = norm),
             cax = cax,
             ticks = bounds,
             boundaries = [0] + bounds[1:-1] + [60])
```

[image]